# Java Char to Integer

Tags: java

I know it's may be an basic question. But I want to be clear.
If I have a java char c which has value '9', can I convert it to int by doing following:
c - '0' ? 
I used to play this and never had problem but someone told it's wrong? And why ?

Comment: `'11'` is not a character.

Comment: It's not "wrong". Some may consider it bad style, but since Java is specified to use Unicode for character encoding, it will always work (provided that `c` is always a decimal digit character).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's wrong, you can do it.

```
int x = '9' - '0';
```

But if you also want it to work for hexadecimal chars 'A' = 10, 'B' = 11, etc you can do it like this

```
int x = Character.getNumericValue('9');
```

Edit: based on other answer in this post
Character.getNumericValue will actually go all the way to 'Z' = 35, so if you want to be safe use

```
int x = Character.digit('9', 10);  // for base 10
int x = Character.digit('9', 16);  // for base 16
int x = Character.digit('B', 16);  // for base 16
```

Comment: You mean `'9' - '0'`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you *can*. But, I would strongly recommend you use [`Character.digit(char, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28char,%20int%29) (where the `int` is the *radix*), something like

```
char ch = '9';
int i = Character.digit(ch, 10);
System.out.printf("ch = %c, i = %d%n", ch, i);
```

The only issue(s) I see with your approach is that it is a little more complicated, and you *should* validate the range

```
if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
```

Comment: +1 for pointing to the right API. However, validation wouldn't be needed if it can be established via other means that `c` is always a decimal digit at that point in the code.